# Unexpected crash / phone randomly turning off

Tags: battery, boot-loop, crashes

i have a samsung s5 with lollipop installed.
The phone seems to randomly turn off.
The phone enters a boot loop until i plug the charger in.
It has happened several times, but i don't know how to reproduce the error.
It doesn't seem to be app specific, but it has crashed while using the following apps.
... When using the camera
... When using chrome
... When using VR zeiss

I have tried the following, but none of these have worked for me.
1. Wiped cache partition x??
2. Factory reset x2
3. Safe mode
4. Battery calibration, charged phone to 100% while off

Has anyone had a similar issue and been able to solve it?